# Add Name Definition to "Function" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, rename, definition

I would like to do something like this :

```
var f = Function;
var f1 = f(){
    //do stuff
}

f1(); // call f1 as a function
```

The main idea is to create a new name and a new way to create a function : instead of doing `function a()` do `f a()`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What would you need this for? Btw, `Function` needs to be *called* to create new functions from code.

Comment: Simply because I want to make my code shorter, even if there is no other big deal...

Comment: If you set a variable to a function, it is already the function. Just call it with the parenthesis.

Comment: You cannot, that would be invalid JS. However, you might want to have a look at some compile-to-javascript languages with much more concise syntax, like coffeescript.org/: `f1 = () -> ;`

Comment: yeah this is the idea, ruby also has a short synthax for function definition, I wanted to redefine symply this in JS, but if it's not possible, too bad ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript provides no means by which you can extend the language with additional keywords.

Comment: and binding a function, split the arguments and do all the binding needed ?

Comment: You aren't trying to use `f` as a function though, so how is that relevant?

Comment: yes I know, but this is because I don't know how to do this and if this is possible...

Comment: @Nobe4 simply put, every time you want to define a function, you have to use the `function` keyword. There is no way around this.

Comment: There are ways around it (the Function constructor function), they are just nasty and more complicated. (And that isn't a one-off lump of nasty, complication, you have to deal with it every time you create a function).

Comment: @basilikum : yeah that what I'm trying to avoid, because I just don't want to type `function` everytime ^^ But I really understand that is a useless question ! @Quentin : yeah I think the goal isn't worth it to dive into such considerations. Thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you meant, but maybe you can play around with this:

```
var f=function(){ 
return function(){alert(1)};  
}; 

var x=f(); 
x();
```